# Simple library for Natural Language Processing in C#

Tags: c#, nlp

I am working on a project which requires simple sort of NLP. The features that I need include:

- Sentence splitter
- Phrase splitter (not word splitter)
- Phrase nature identifier (common noun, proper noun, verb etc.)

I am aware of libraries like SharpNLP, NLPTK and Antelope but all of them are too big and fancy for my project. Can someone suggest a simple one that provides only the above mentioned features. If it is a bit bigger and provides other features that's ok but I guess having a 139MB large library for this simple stuff might not be a good idea, especially when this project is already going to be complex in other areas.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I asked this question so that I don't have to think about tens (at the minimum) ways two sentences can be splitted (still missing some scenarios) and write complex re's for them... Phrase splitter and their nature identifiers are way difficult and not for individual work I guess.

Comment: "a 139MB large library" sounds rather smallish.

Comment: Thinking that the work routinely done by a massively parallel computing network is *simple* is a gross mistake.  Use your noggin.

Comment: If by "phrase nature identifier" you mean a POS tagger, then 139MB is indeed quite small. In fact, I just trained a sentence splitter whose model was about this size.

Comment: Ya, that's what I meant. Finding that nothing is smaller,I am using SharpNLP now. Seems good.